# How to automatically apply Release Updates?

Tags: lightning, security

I see the with the new Release Updates page there is now an API to list release updates in the Tooling API as a [ReleaseUpdate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_releaseupdate.htm) sobject. There is also a `ReleaseUpdateStep` and `ReleaseUpdateStepLog` available, but they are undocumented.

If I want to programmatically enable Release Updates is there an easy way to do this and/or already available tool? The UI is all Aura and not easy to script against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such way right now. The object states that it supports: `describeSObjects()`, `query()`. So, for now, you can still only apply Critical Updates using the UI; this object provides read-only access to the features for now. Perhaps there'll be an update to update the status in the future, but now is not that future. You'll want to watch future Release Notes to see if salesforce.com enables additional functionality, but for now, all we have is a read-only interface.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that it's not updatable but ReleaseUpdateStep actually is updatable based on the describe API, so it seems like it might be possible to do it. Anyway, I ended up writing a Puppeteer script to do it for me on my orgs.